# const parameters in a const member function

Tags: c++, constants, function-qualifier

I have read about use cases of const and I feel like I have a good understanding of const for the most part. However, I can't seem to figure out why I don't see this more often:

```
void someFunction(const string& A) const
```

Where you have a const parameter in a const member function. For some reason, whenever I look up examples and the function is const, the const seems to be stripped off the parameters like this:

```
void someFunction(string& A) const
```

However that doesn't seem to stop me from modifying A. Is it considered bad form to have const parameters in a const member function?

What is the reasoning for not keeping the const in the parameters as well if A would not be modified?

EDIT: This is my fault for not clarifying but I understood the difference between adding it before the parameter and adding it after the function. A lot of code I looked at just never combined the two and I was just trying to figure out if there was a reason for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Const correctness: const char const \* const GetName const (//stuff);](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835399/const-correctness-const-char-const-const-getname-const-stuff)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void someFunction(const string& A) const
```

The last `const` means that the method will not change the state of the object referenced by `*this` inside it. The first `const` is saying that the function will not change the state of the argument - and it doesn't have any correlation with the second `const`, so you may have this:

```
void someFunction(string& A) const
```

In this case function may change state of `A` argument, but it may not change the state of its object.

For example (and this is a highly hypothetical example):

```
class MyIntArray
{
 // some magic here in order to implement this array    

public:
 void copy_to_vector(std::vector<int> &v) const
 {
    // copy data from this object into the vector.
    // this will modify the vector, but not the
    // current object.
 }

}
```

And this is the example where these two are combined:

```
class MyOutput
{
    char prefix;
    // This class contains some char which
    // will be used as prefix to all vectors passed to it
public:
     MyOutput(char c):prefix(c){}
     void output_to_cout(const std::vector<int> &i) const
     {
        // iterate trough vector (using const_iterator) and output each element
        // prefixed with c - this will not change nor the vector
        // nor the object.
     }

}
```

Oh, and take a look into this question: [Use of 'const' for function parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117293/use-of-const-for-function-parameters)

Comment: That's what I was figuring. However, I just haven't seen them used together in the examples I have been able to find and was just trying to figure out if there was a reason for that.

It may just be that the examples were just kept simple and didn't combine them, but I tried to see if there was a reason I never saw it that way. This clarifies my assumption. Thanks.

Comment: @Nabren I've added the small example (the only I could think of in 1:41AM).

Comment: Ya, I understand that completely. I guess I can't even get the question out right.

Put it this way, I always see it written like this:

"void copy_to_vector(std::vector<int> &v) const"

Even in cases where v is not modified. So I was wondering why it just wouldn't be written like this:

"void copy_to_vector(const std::vector<int> &v) const"

Is all. From what I can gather from the answers here, it should. I just find it odd I don't see it like that more often if that's the case.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, if the argument (reference or pointer) is not modified, it should be written with `const` specifier .

Answer (score 2):

`const` on a function only applies to member functions.  It states that the class object will not be modified.  It does not mean that a function parameter passed by reference cannot be modified.

Passing a parameter to a function as `const &` prevents you from modifying the parameter.

```
class A
{
private:
    int data;
public:
    void func1(const std::string& s) const; // s cannot be modified, members of A cannot
    void func2(std::string& s) const; // s can be modified, members of A cannot

    void func3(const std::string& s); // s cannot be modified, members of A can be
    void func4(std::string& s); // s can be modified, as can members of A
};
```

The functions labeled `const` cannot change `data`, but no such restriction is on `s` unless it is labeled `const`.

Comment: you should give A members to make the example clearer. But Good answer. +1